# Annotated Spring MVC @ModelAttribute automapping not working with associated objects

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC with Annotations. Here's a quick outline of my problem.

My Domain:

```
public class Restaurant {    
    private String name;
    private Address address = new Address();
    //Get and set....
}

public class Address{
    private String street;
    //Get and set....
}
```

My Controller:

```
//Configure and show restaurant form.
public ModelAndView showAction() {
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/restaurant/showRestaurant");
   restaurant = new Restaurant();
   mav.addObject("restaurant", restaurant);
   return mav;
}

//Save restaurant
public ModelAndView saveAction(@ModelAttribute(value="restaurant") Restaurant restaurant,BindingResult result) {
    restaurant.getName();//<- Not is null
    restaurant.getAddress().getStreet(); //<- is null
}
```

My View:

```
 <form>
    <span class="full addr1"> 
      <label for="Nome">Name<span class="req">*</span></label>
      <h:inputText class="field text large" value="#{restaurant.name}" 
         id="name" forceId="true" styleClass="field text addr"/>
    </span> 

    <span class="full addr1">
      <label for="Nome">Street <span class="req">*</span></label>
      <h:inputText class="field text large" value="#{restaurant.address.street}" 
         id="street" forceId="true" styleClass="field text addr"/>
    </span>  
 </form>
```

My problem is, when I fill the name and the street to call the method "saveAction" when I try to get the restaurant filled happens that the name comes from the street but did not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that familliar with jsf, but for binding in spring you generally need the full path, i.e. `name="address.street"`, in order to get the street name bound properly

Comment: but the "h: inputText" is not the name property

Answer (score 0):

Try binding using the spring form tags http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html. Its pretty easy.

Comment: is to use this form with jsf spring because my pages are. xhtml
I had tried but could not place you know you can use?

Comment: I got what you are saying, i think jsf also manages beans and spring also manages bean. i am not sure whether both can be mixed up. I will try to figure out.

Comment: i think spring faces has some integration touch point with JSF. Please take a look at this http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0-m1/reference/spring-faces.html. It might help you.